# How to navigate away from MasterDetailPage but not reset the navigation stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I finally found away (since PushAsync() doesn't work globally) how to navigate to a next page from a MasterDetailPage like so:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Screen_Profile());
```

This opens a new page, but then I cannot go back to the previous page, but this is resetting the navigation stack.

How can I navigate away but still have the option of returning to MasterDetail page navigation?

Comment: Have you tried to add the MasterDetailPage into a NavigationPage,like `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourMasterDetailPage ());` in app.cs

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
 Navigation.PushAsync(new Screen_Profile());
```

try to read more on this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical

Comment: it says "push async is not supported globall

Comment: @user13397492 You could show a sketch to describe the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the reference about the navigation with masterDetailpage](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47444/best-practice-mvvm-navigation-using-master-detail-page)

In your App.cs you would have something similar to this code (apologies if it doesn't compile, I am coding this off the top of my head).

```
public static NavigationPage NavPage = null;

public App()
{
    var _navPage = new NavigationPage(new PageOne());

    var _masterPage = new MasterDetailpage();
    _masterPage.Detail = NavPage;
    _masterPage.Master = (your master / menu page);

    MainPage = _masterPage;

}
```

Then in your code you can reference

```
await App.NavPage.PushAsync(new PageTwo());
```

That gets you functional. However you don't want to access the NavigationPage this way. You can use DependencyInjection to create a NavigationService.

Something like

```
public class NavigationService: INavigationService
{

      public NavigationService(NavigationPage navPage)
      {
            // Keep local copy of navPage
      }

      public async Task NavigateTo(Page page)
      {

            await _navPage.PushAsync(page);

      }

      public async Task GoBack()
      {

            await _navPage.PopAsync();

      }

}
```

You should use like this Pattern to navigate.